# How to open device message application in iPhone and Android using cordova

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, cordova-2.0.0

I have a button in my app, I want that when I click on this inbuilt message box is open of device(iPhone & Android). I am using cordova, jquery and html5.

Please help me on this.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="sms:12343123">Send SMS</a>
```

Comment: no... this is plain HTML... Read http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007891-SW1